# Hair Comb not working

Tags: particles, hair

I'am trying to make a rug with all the simple particle rug settings. I want to comb the hair with particle edit but whenever i enter particle edit mode, my hair settings all distort up.
This is what it looks like in object Mode
[image: Hair_Before_distorting]
Right when I enter edit particle mode, this happens
[image: Distorted]
Getting out of particle edit doesnt fix this and i have to undo everything[image: Object_Mode_Distortion]. I only need to comb the hair. Please help.

Comment: I'm probably wrong but try applying scale, and change emit from setting. Does your plane have edges where bald spots are created?

Comment: Applying scale doesn't work either. No there arent bald edges

Answer (score 0):

Delete any custom normals or Vertex Groups on your object properties. Delete any other irrelevant information (this is caused by a Smoothing Group from other software).

Also check you don´t have unchecked the eye icon and the edit icon on one of your modifiers. This is the reason why you see something in *Edit Mode* and something else in *Object Mode*.

Last but not least, you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> on your rug to apply transformations.